# PHP being triggered from email hyperlinks

Tags: php, email

I am having an issue with the PHP I insert into emails being triggered. I have a "confirm email" button in emails I am sending to users, that looks something like:

```
<a href="url.com/confirm-email/?user=139">Click Here To Confirm</a>
```

And then in the link I will have.

```
$userid=$_GET['user']; 
/////then run below query (leaving out mysqli function)
UPDATE users SET confirmed=1 WHERE user_id='$userid'
```

The logic is that the query won't run until the user clicks the link the email. However, the query is running as soon as the user opens the email. It's almost as if their email is crawling the link and triggering the query. Is there any way to prevent this?

Comment: You need `https://` at the beginning of the URL.

Comment: I've never heard of email automatically clicking links like that. You don't need to prevent something that shouldn't happen in the first place.

Comment: Something else is causing this, post the complete email body.

Comment: If this is actually happening the way you describe, your users should *really* use a different email client.  Also, important side note, your PHP code is (1) a series of syntax errors and (2) once those are corrected, wide open to SQL injection.